# How to temporarily Disable Access for Entire Org?

Tags: security

How to temporarily Disable Access for Entire Org?

For all Internal

and/or

All External users.

Comment: Login IP restrictions

Comment: Wouldn't an option be to set login hours temporarily so they are temporarily locked out? Seems like less of a hassle than freezing a bunch of accounts as it can be done via profiles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Piggy backing on Rodrigo, here is a link to [knowledge article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000187696&language=en_US&type=1) to freeze multiple users at once. I would recommend freezing rather than marking inactive as it will allow integrations to continue to run.

Another caveat, make sure to leave any integration users off of this list as well as yours.

Comment: Good point @Brio87

Answer (score 1):

I would export all user's ids along with the Active field.

**MAKE SURE YOU LEAVE YOUR USER OUT OF THIS LIST.**

Mass update the users to make them inactive.

Comment: I feel like that's a bootleg way.

Is there not a switch somewhere internally?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable all users except Administrators using open-source [VsCode plugin sfdx-hardis](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NicolasVuillamy.vscode-sfdx-hardis) :)

[image]

You can see details in the following article

https://medium.com/@dimitrimonge/freeze-unfreeze-users-during-salesforce-deployment-8a1488bf8dd3

*Disclaimer: I work in the company providing this open-source plugin*